# How to make a PDF using the text in a EditText in android?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to make a PDF using a text in a EditText (TextView) in android.
This is my code, but it is not working.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    TextView ocrResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_pdf:
            // PDF
            try {
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("TextFile", MODE_APPEND));
                EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                out.write(text);
                out.write('\n');
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, tem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
       default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem when you are using  this code?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: When I click it, the toast shows "The contents are saved in the file."
But there is no any PDF saved in my phone memory